# Wave packet change

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, fourier-transform, time-evolution, unitarity

Is it possible for a wave packet to change shape as it travels, possibly scattering and having interaction. For ex., can an initial gaussian become lorentzian after some interaction. To conserve unitarity, area underneath packet should be conserved I think. Other than that, cannot the relative amplitudes ir phases of fourier series terms change so that shape changes? If so , has something been derived about conditions about what can change to what? Or maybe it is too general a possibility to consider and derive.

Comment: Most time dependent wave packets change their shape during their evolution. Wave packets that keep their shape are actually a special case; for example coherent states or gaussians in harmonic potentials.

Comment: See the graphics in [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet#Gaussian_wave_packets_in_quantum_mechanics). This is a recondite, hit-or-miss area.  For the SHO, non-Gaussian states wiggle and morph as they oscillate, but after a period they "magically" revert to their original shape and start anew! This is easy to see in phase-space QM.

Comment: ...for instance, look at the x-profile underneath the phase-space-rotating [cat state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasiprobability_distribution#Harmonic_oscillator_time_evolution)!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Hans Wurst: wavepackets are superpositions of eigenstates, typically quite large superpositions, and hence the way thay superpose changes with time. Even the coherent state of the harmonic oscillator, for which the amplitude of the packet is a moving Gaussian with unchanged shape, the phase structure still changes with time.

For examples of wavepackets and their time evolution for the particle in a box problem see
[https://users.physics.ox.ac.uk/~palmerc/wavepacket.htm](https://users.physics.ox.ac.uk/%7Epalmerc/wavepacket.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, wave packets of any nature can change their shape (without any scattering and interactions), although a gaussian shape becoming a Lorentz one would require some rather special conditions. This distortion happens due to different harmonics composing the the wave packet having different *phase velocities*, $v_{ph}=\omega/k$ - a phenomenon, known as *dispersion*, whereas the relationship between the frequency and the wave number is known as *dispersion law*. The propagation of the shape of the packet is characterized by *group velocity*, $v_g=\partial \omega/\partial k$. Since the information is encoded in the shape of a signal, it is this latter that cannot exceed the speed of light.